# Why is "this" captured in a closure?

Tags: javascript

If I create a variable, say _this, and assign it to this, it is captured as a closure and not a reference to the current version of this.  Why?

Example code:

```
var AnimCore = (function () {
    function AnimCore(ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    AnimCore.prototype.beginAnimation = function () {
        this.animLoop();
    };
    AnimCore.prototype.animLoop = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.ctx.drawSomething(); // removed actual drawing code, this is a proxy for it.
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            _this.animLoop();
        }, 1000 / 60);
    };
    return AnimCore;
})();
```

In this case, _this is bound to the initial this and not to the new this each time the function is called.  Why?

[update]
I now understand that the closure is happening in the anonymous function which is why _this always refers to the same thing.  Next question, however, is why does this.ctx work each time?  If I don't use the anonymous function, it fails after the first time.

Comment: I'm not getting the question. Why? because this is how javascript closure works...

Comment: Asked differently - what exactly do you expect to happen? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Christoph, see my update.  The code is slightly updated.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a special variable. It's special because its context is determined at the time you call the function with `this` inside.

If, however, you're assigning `this` to a variable, inside a closure:

```
var myFunc = (function () {
    var staticThis = this;
    return function () {
        staticThis.doStuff();
    };
}).call(myObj);
```

See what I've done?
I've got a variable called `staticThis`, which I am explicitly setting to be equal to `myObj`.
`staticThis` keeps the ***value*** of `this` (which happens to be a pointer to a specific object), rather than keeping the "magic" dynamic context resolution of `this`, which is saved for the `this` keyword.